# Finding one of the two unknown potentials with a given voltage of a net reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

A half-cell consisting of palladium rod dipping into a $1\ M$ $\ce{Pd(NO_3)_2}$ solution is connected with a standard hydrogen half-cell. The cell voltage is $0.99\ volt$ and the platinum electrode in the hydrogen half-cell is the anode. Determine $E^ο$ for the reaction $\ce{Pd\longrightarrow Pd^{2+} + 2e}$.

Now the question is: can I find a numerical value of the needed $E^ο$, if I can't use half-cell potential of $\ce{Pt^{2+}\!−\!Pt}$?

Comment: You have the overall cell voltage, so you should be able to leave the E0 as unknown and solve for it.

Comment: Careful, in the [standard hydrogen electrode](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Analytical_Chemistry/Electrochemistry/Electrodes/Standard_Hydrogen_Electrode) the redox reaction is **not** $Pt^{2+} + 2e^- -> Pt$.